# Java hasn`t see files, which downloaded, till I manualy update it

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, file, download

In my Java Swing app I load pictures from web, using `RandomAccessFile` class. When downloading complete, the thumbnail should be shown, but it doesn't and it throws exception "File not found". But, when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> in my Eclipse on those folder in which files were downloaded to, the files appear in it, and my app works correctly after that, and thumbnails are shown. Please, help, what I have to do to update files automatic?

Comment: What happens when you run your code outside of Eclipse? (Eclipse does caching of many things relating to the filesystem; I don't know if that is tripping you up here, but let's start by eliminating it from the set of possible problems.)

Comment: I don`t ran it outside yet. Thank you, I`ll try it

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not calling close() after the download.

Comment: I close streams and handlers, I recognized it

Comment: I can`t type it here. But look at this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C5IVADo0sTO2-Vg1b9ytxqSe9snkmBLe_GB8Ei0su4c/edit

Comment: A couple of things:

1.- In Java you don't need to declare all variables at the beginning like you do on C.

2.- Make sure those closes are not throwing excpetions, if they were  you wouldn't be noticing with those empty catch blocks.

3.- Why are you using RandomAccessFile when you're not randomly accessing the file? For sequential writes there's outputstream. Try if that causes the error too.

Comment: Thank you. Although mistake was in class, which read downloaded picture, but I made what you suggested, and understood, that mistake is not in the download class